# delete nodes from xml file having duplicate ID using xsl

Tags: xml, node.js, xslt

I have xml as below:

```
<panel id="MainPanel" x="0" y="0" w="100%" h="100%" backgroundcolor="green" >

  <panel id="somepanel" x="0" y="130" w="100%" h="PANEL_ALIGN" backgroundcolor="red" >
    <panel id="nextpanel" x="0" y="130" w="100%" h="PANEL_ALIGN" backgroundcolor="red" >
       <table id="TestPanel" x="1%" y="20" w="98%" h="PANEL_ALIGN""></table>
       <table id="TestPanel" x="1%" y="20" w="98%" h="PANEL_ALIGN""></table>
       <table id="TestPanel2" x="1%" y="20" w="98%" h="PANEL_ALIGN""></table>
     </panel>
  </panel>
```

Expected is:

```
<panel id="MainPanel" x="0" y="0" w="100%" h="100%" backgroundcolor="green" >

  <panel id="somepanel" x="0" y="130" w="100%" h="PANEL_ALIGN" backgroundcolor="red" >
    <panel id="nextpanel" x="0" y="130" w="100%" h="PANEL_ALIGN" backgroundcolor="red" >
    <table id="TestPanel" x="1%" y="20" w="98%" h="PANEL_ALIGN""></table>
      <table id="TestPanel2" x="1%" y="20" w="98%" h="PANEL_ALIGN""></table>
     </panel>
</panel>
```

I use below xsl to remove table node but it removes all table node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template
 match="table"/>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could anyone help , as i dont knwo much of xslt.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your stylesheet as a top level:

```
<xsl:key name="kTable" match="table" use="@id"/>
```

and replace

```
<xsl:template match="table"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="table[generate-id() != generate-id(key('kTable', @id)[1])]"/>
```

Comment: what is kTable variable mean.

Comment: but if some other tag is there like <testtag id="testID"> twice than its not working :(

Comment: Its working :) I have done as below instead creating another key. <xsl:key name="kTable" match="table|testtag" use="@id"/>. Thanks for ur help. It resolved my issue :)

Comment: Is there any way to make it generic , means can it be applied in such a way that any type of xml node having repetative ID will be removed.